# Change data type in columns of dataframe with duplicate column header

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
DTYYYYMMDD  TICKER      CLOSE   ...    DTYYYYMMDD  TICKER   CLOSE
0    19970102     AEF    18.7489   ...      20190222     AEF  7.2500
1    19970102     CVM  1093.7500   ...      20190222     CVM  2.8800
2    19970102     CMT     2.3125   ...      20190222     CMT  7.9750
3    19970102  BKTI.K     3.3750   ...      20190222  BKTI.K  4.0300
```

I want to change all of the DTYYYYMMDD columns data type from int to date, from 19970102 to 1997-01-02. I tried the following code

```
stock_dataframe['DTYYYYMMDD'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_dataframe['DTYYYYMMDD'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
```

I got the following error: "ValueError: cannot assemble with duplicate keys"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those rare situations I'll recommend `apply`:

```
df['DTYYYYMMDD'] = df['DTYYYYMMDD'].astype(str).apply(
    pd.to_datetime, format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce'
)
df

  DTYYYYMMDD  TICKER      CLOSE DTYYYYMMDD  TICKER  CLOSE
0 1997-01-02     AEF    18.7489 2019-02-22     AEF  7.250
1 1997-01-02     CVM  1093.7500 2019-02-22     CVM  2.880
2 1997-01-02     CMT     2.3125 2019-02-22     CMT  7.975
3 1997-01-02  BKTI.K     3.3750 2019-02-22  BKTI.K  4.030
```

---

A more robust version of my answer taking performance into consideration.

```
if isinstance(df['DTYYYYMMDD'], pd.DataFrame):
    df['DTYYYYMMDD'] = df['DTYYYYMMDD'].astype(str).apply(...)
else:
    df['DTYYYYMMDD'] = pd.to_datetime(...)
```

This is useful if you're not sure when there are duplicate columns (and when there aren't).